# Table id as an integer made of different column values

Tags: mysql, database-design

Having an archive of a given structure:
Box
-folder
-envelope
-file
I'd like to give every cell of the table (which holds info about every file) an unique ID that would consist of their parent structure and look like this:
box\envelope\file

As envelope and file numbers can repeat in different boxes, having such ID system could ease up keeping the base clean I think.

How should I construct a column to store such info in a way presented above?

Comment: You shouldn't , just make the PK of the table as the combination of them  .

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to do it this way:
`ALTER TABLE 'scans' DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(box, folder, envelope, file);`
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, as I get the error #1075.

Comment: Also, does the PK need to be set as A_I? If so, I cannot use it as an option in my database as it won't fit into my needs.

Comment: Please provide the current `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With that, we should be able to help you the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same `ALTER`, add this clause: `DROP COLUMN id`.  This assumes that `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  CAUTION:  If you are `JOINing` to this table via `id`, this will have a disastrous impact.  Please provide more information about current usage of `id`, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.